Indexing and optimize large query with multiple joins
I have search query with multiple table join as
SELECT
    DISTINCT pp.person_profile_id,
    pp.middle_name,
    pp.prefix,
    pp.first_name,
    pp.last_name,
    pp.suffix,
    pp.privacy_type,
    pp.gender,
    pp.gender_class,
    pp.birth_date,
    pp.birth_place_id,
    pp.death_date,
    pp.death_place_id,
    pp.profile_photo_s3_path,
    pp.profile_photo_size,
    pp.created_by,
    pp.created_on_date,
    pp.updated_by,
    pp.updated_on_date,
    pp.life_status,
    pp.user_id,
    pp.deleted_status,
    pp.bd_approximation,
    pp.bd_year,
    pp.bd_month,
    pp.bd_season,
    pp.dd_approximation,
    pp.dd_year,
    pp.dd_month,
    pp.dd_season,
    pp.display_name,
    pp.secondary_name,
    pp.profile_creation_type,
    date_format(pp.birth_date, '%b %d, %Y') as formated_birth_date,
    date_format(pp.death_date, '%b %d, %Y') as formated_death_date,
(
        CASE
            WHEN pp.display_name IS NOT NULL THEN pp.display_name
            ELSE trim(
                concat(
                    COALESCE(pp.first_name, ''),
                    ' ',
                    COALESCE(pp.middle_name, ''),
                    ' ',
                    COALESCE(pp.last_name, '')
                )
            )
        END
    ) final_person_name
FROM
    tbl_person_profile AS pp
    LEFT JOIN tbl_address as ba ON pp.birth_place_id = ba.id
    OR pp.death_place_id = ba.id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_address_book as a ON pp.person_profile_id = a.person_profile_id
    AND a.is_active = '1'
    LEFT JOIN tbl_address as ad ON a.address_id = ad.id
    AND ad.deleted_status = '0'
    LEFT JOIN tbl_person_relationships as prf ON pp.person_profile_id = prf.focus_person_id
    OR pp.person_profile_id = prf.related_person_id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_additional_names as an ON pp.person_profile_id = an.person_profile_id
    LEFT JOIN tbl_person_profile_storytelling as pps ON pp.person_profile_id = pps.person_profile_id
    AND pps.deleted_status = '0'
    LEFT JOIN tbl_person_profile as storytelling_person ON find_in_set(
        storytelling_person.person_profile_id,
        pps.story_writer_ids
    ) > 0
    AND storytelling_person.deleted_status = '0'
    LEFT JOIN tbl_indexer_vital_record as ivr ON (
        pp.person_profile_id = ivr.person_profile_id
        OR find_in_set(pp.person_profile_id, ivr.provider_value) > 0
        OR find_in_set(pp.person_profile_id, ivr.attendees_value) > 0
        OR find_in_set(pp.person_profile_id, ivr.contact_person_value) > 0
        OR find_in_set(pp.person_profile_id, ivr.focus_person_value) > 0
        OR find_in_set(pp.person_profile_id, ivr.death_attendees_value) > 0
        OR find_in_set(pp.person_profile_id, ivr.death_attendant_value) > 0
    )
    LEFT JOIN tbl_indexer_location as il ON pp.person_profile_id = il.person_profile_id
    OR (
        find_in_set(pp.person_profile_id, il.profile_value) > 0
        AND il.profile_key = 'Person'
    )
    AND il.deleted_status = '0'
    LEFT JOIN tbl_indexer_physical_apperance as ipa ON (
        pp.person_profile_id = ipa.person_profile_id
        OR find_in_set(pp.person_profile_id, ipa.artist_value) > 0
        OR find_in_set(pp.person_profile_id, ipa.focus_person_value) > 0
    )
    LEFT JOIN tbl_indexer_event_details as ied ON (
        pp.person_profile_id = ied.person_profile_id
        OR find_in_set(pp.person_profile_id, ied.union_partner_value) > 0
        OR find_in_set(pp.person_profile_id, ied.officiant_value) > 0
        OR find_in_set(pp.person_profile_id, ied.attendees_value) > 0
        OR find_in_set(pp.person_profile_id, ied.focus_person_value) > 0
    )
    LEFT JOIN tbl_event_vendor as ev_search ON find_in_set(ev_search.id, ied.event_vendor) > 0
    LEFT JOIN tbl_event_organizer as eo_search ON find_in_set(eo_search.id, ied.event_organizer) > 0
    LEFT JOIN tbl_person_profile as ppe ON (
        find_in_set(ppe.person_profile_id, ied.union_partner_value) > 0
        OR find_in_set(ppe.person_profile_id, ied.officiant_value) > 0
        OR find_in_set(ppe.person_profile_id, ied.attendees_value) > 0
        OR find_in_set(ppe.person_profile_id, ied.focus_person_value) > 0
        OR find_in_set(ppe.person_profile_id, ivr.provider_value) > 0
        OR find_in_set(ppe.person_profile_id, ivr.attendees_value) > 0
        OR find_in_set(ppe.person_profile_id, ivr.contact_person_value) > 0
        OR find_in_set(ppe.person_profile_id, ivr.focus_person_value) > 0
        OR find_in_set(ppe.person_profile_id, ivr.death_attendees_value) > 0
        OR find_in_set(ppe.person_profile_id, ivr.death_attendant_value) > 0
        OR find_in_set(ppe.person_profile_id, ipa.artist_value) > 0
        OR find_in_set(ppe.person_profile_id, ipa.focus_person_value) > 0
        OR (
            find_in_set(
                ppe.person_profile_id,
                ev_search.vendor_name_value
            ) > 0
            AND ev_search.vendor_name_key = 'Person'
        )
        OR find_in_set(
            ppe.person_profile_id,
            ev_search.contact_person_value
        ) > 0
        OR (
            find_in_set(
                ppe.person_profile_id,
                eo_search.event_organizer_value
            ) > 0
            AND eo_search.event_organizer_key = 'Person'
        )
        OR find_in_set(
            ppe.person_profile_id,
            eo_search.contact_person_value
        ) > 0
    )
    AND ppe.deleted_status = '0'
    LEFT JOIN tbl_event_vendor as ev ON pp.person_profile_id = ev.vendor_name_value
    AND ev.vendor_name_key = 'Person'
    AND ev.vendor_location_key = 'Map'
    LEFT JOIN tbl_location_profile as locp ON (
        find_in_set(locp.location_profile_id, il.location_value) > 0
        OR find_in_set(locp.location_profile_id, ied.location_info_value) > 0
        OR find_in_set(locp.location_profile_id, ied.ceremony_value) > 0
        OR find_in_set(locp.location_profile_id, ied.reception_value) > 0
        OR find_in_set(locp.location_profile_id, ivr.location_value) > 0
        OR find_in_set(
            locp.location_profile_id,
            ivr.death_location_value
        ) > 0
        OR find_in_set(locp.location_profile_id, ipa.location_value) > 0
        OR find_in_set(
            locp.location_profile_id,
            ev_search.vendor_location_value
        ) > 0
    )
    AND locp.deleted_status = '0'
    LEFT JOIN tbl_company_profile as cp ON find_in_set(cp.company_profile_id, ipa.company_value) > 0
    OR (
        find_in_set(
            cp.company_profile_id,
            ev_search.vendor_name_value
        ) > 0
        AND ev_search.vendor_name_key = 'Company'
    )
    OR (
        find_in_set(
            cp.company_profile_id,
            eo_search.event_organizer_value
        ) > 0
        AND eo_search.event_organizer_key = 'Company'
    )
    AND cp.deleted_status = '0'
WHERE
    pp.user_id = 540
    AND pp.catalog_id = 320
    AND pp.deleted_status != '1'
    AND (
        pp.display_name LIKE '%living%'
        OR pp.prefix LIKE '%living%'
        OR pp.suffix LIKE '%living%'
        OR pp.first_name LIKE '%living%'
        OR pp.last_name LIKE '%living%'
        OR pp.middle_name LIKE '%living%'
        OR concat_ws(' ', pp.first_name, pp.last_name) LIKE '%living%'
        OR concat_ws(' ', pp.first_name, pp.middle_name, pp.last_name) LIKE '%living%'
        OR pp.privacy_type LIKE '%living%'
        OR pp.gender LIKE '%living%'
        OR pp.life_status LIKE '%living%'
        OR pp.display_name LIKE '%living%'
        OR pp.secondary_name LIKE '%living%'
        OR pp.lds_number LIKE '%living%'
        OR pp.bd_approximation LIKE '%living%'
        OR pp.bd_year LIKE '%living%'
        OR pp.bd_month LIKE '%living%'
        OR pp.bd_season LIKE '%living%'
        OR pp.dd_approximation LIKE '%living%'
        OR pp.dd_year LIKE '%living%'
        OR pp.dd_month LIKE '%living%'
        OR pp.dd_year LIKE '%living%'
        OR pp.dd_season LIKE '%living%'
        OR DATE(pp.birth_date) LIKE '%living%'
        OR DATE(pp.death_date) LIKE '%living%'
        OR ba.current_address LIKE '%living%'
        OR ba.vintage_address LIKE '%living%'
        OR ba.vintage_address_notes LIKE '%living%'
        OR ba.country LIKE '%living%'
        OR ba.state LIKE '%living%'
        OR ba.state LIKE '%living%'
        OR ba.state LIKE '%living%'
        OR ba.zipcode LIKE '%living%'
        OR ba.street_address LIKE '%living%'
        OR ba.neighborhood LIKE '%living%'
        OR ba.county LIKE '%living%'
        OR ba.note LIKE '%living%'
        OR a.email LIKE '%living%'
        OR a.mobile_no LIKE '%living%'
        OR a.phone_no LIKE '%living%'
        OR a.address_type LIKE '%living%'
        OR a.lds_number LIKE '%living%'
        OR a.web_address LIKE '%living%'
        OR ad.current_address LIKE '%living%'
        OR ad.vintage_address LIKE '%living%'
        OR ad.vintage_address_notes LIKE '%living%'
        OR ad.country LIKE '%living%'
        OR ad.state LIKE '%living%'
        OR ad.city LIKE '%living%'
        OR ad.zipcode LIKE '%living%'
        OR ad.street_address LIKE '%living%'
        OR ad.neighborhood LIKE '%living%'
        OR ad.county LIKE '%living%'
        OR ad.note LIKE '%living%'
        OR prf.family_or_nonfamily LIKE '%living%'
        OR prf.connection_type LIKE '%living%'
        OR prf.focus_person_to_related_person_relation_specific_role LIKE '%living%'
        OR prf.focus_person_to_related_person_relation_family_side LIKE '%living%'
        OR prf.focus_person_to_related_person_relation_sibling_type LIKE '%living%'
        OR prf.focus_person_to_related_person_relation_multiple_birth_type_type LIKE '%living%'
        OR prf.focus_person_to_related_person_relation_zygosity LIKE '%living%'
        OR prf.focus_person_to_related_person_relation_donor_surrogate LIKE '%living%'
        OR prf.focus_person_to_related_person_relation_donor_conceived LIKE '%living%'
        OR prf.focus_person_to_related_person_relation_gestational_type LIKE '%living%'
        OR prf.related_person_to_focus_person_relation_role LIKE '%living%'
        OR prf.related_person_to_focus_person_relation_specific_role LIKE '%living%'
        OR prf.related_person_to_focus_person_relation_family_side LIKE '%living%'
        OR prf.related_person_to_focus_person_relation_sibling_type LIKE '%living%'
        OR prf.related_person_to_focus_person_relation_multiple_birth_type_type LIKE '%living%'
        OR prf.related_person_to_focus_person_relation_zygosity LIKE '%living%'
        OR prf.related_person_to_focus_person_relation_donor_surrogate LIKE '%living%'
        OR prf.related_person_to_focus_person_relation_donor_conceived LIKE '%living%'
        OR prf.related_person_to_focus_person_relation_gestational_type LIKE '%living%'
        OR prf.relationship_status LIKE '%living%'
        OR an.prefix LIKE '%living%'
        OR an.first_name LIKE '%living%'
        OR an.last_name LIKE '%living%'
        OR an.middle_name LIKE '%living%'
        OR an.suffix LIKE '%living%'
        OR an.type LIKE '%living%'
        OR an.notes LIKE '%living%'
        OR an.birth_approximation LIKE '%living%'
        OR an.birth_year LIKE '%living%'
        OR an.birth_month LIKE '%living%'
        OR an.birth_season LIKE '%living%'
        OR concat_ws(' ', an.first_name, an.last_name) LIKE '%living%'
        OR concat_ws(' ', an.first_name, an.middle_name, an.last_name) LIKE '%living%'
        OR pps.caption LIKE '%living%'
        OR pps.storytelling LIKE '%living%'
        OR pps.story_writer LIKE '%living%'
        OR pps.record_audio_name LIKE '%living%'
        OR pps.recorded_audio_transcription LIKE '%living%'
        OR pps.upload_audio_name LIKE '%living%'
        OR pps.uploaded_audio_transcription LIKE '%living%'
        OR concat_ws(
            ' ',
            storytelling_person.first_name,
            storytelling_person.middle_name,
            storytelling_person.last_name
        ) LIKE '%living%'
        OR storytelling_person.display_name LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.indexer_header_type LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.indexer_header_sub_type LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.birth_time LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.death_time LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.date LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.death_date LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.date_approximation LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.date_year LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.date_month LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.date_season LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.death_approximation LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.death_year LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.death_month LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.death_season LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.birth_gender LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.birth_type LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.birth_presentation LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.facility LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.death_cause LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.disposition_method LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.disposition_sub_method LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.is_embalmed LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.section LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.plot LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.inscription LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.reason LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.age LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.height LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.weight LIKE '%living%'
        OR concat_ws(' ', ivr.age, ivr.age_measure) LIKE '%living%'
        OR concat_ws(' ', ivr.height, ivr.height_measure) LIKE '%living%'
        OR concat_ws(' ', ivr.weight, ivr.weight_measure) LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.eye_color LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.hair_color LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.skin_color LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.handed LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.blood_type LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.gender LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.physical_description LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.subtopic LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.ethnicity LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.sexual_orientation LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.timeline_source LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.personal_id_number LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.location_value LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.death_location_value LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.death_location_value LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.notes LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.indexer_vital_record_notes LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.death_notes LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.provider_value LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.attendees_value LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.contact_person_value LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.death_attendant_value LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.death_attendees_value LIKE '%living%'
        OR ivr.focus_person_value LIKE '%living%'
        OR il.indexer_header_type LIKE '%living%'
        OR il.indexer_header_sub_type LIKE '%living%'
        OR il.acquisition_type LIKE '%living%'
        OR il.start_date LIKE '%living%'
        OR il.end_date LIKE '%living%'
        OR il.start_date_approximation LIKE '%living%'
        OR il.start_date_year LIKE '%living%'
        OR il.start_date_month LIKE '%living%'
        OR il.start_date_season LIKE '%living%'
        OR il.end_date_approximation LIKE '%living%'
        OR il.end_date_year LIKE '%living%'
        OR il.end_date_month LIKE '%living%'
        OR il.end_date_season LIKE '%living%'
        OR il.relationship_to_location LIKE '%living%'
        OR il.timeline_source LIKE '%living%'
        OR il.location_type LIKE '%living%'
        OR il.location_sub_type LIKE '%living%'
        OR il.name_company LIKE '%living%'
        OR il.reason LIKE '%living%'
        OR il.type_of_build LIKE '%living%'
        OR il.location_value LIKE '%living%'
        OR il.notes LIKE '%living%'
        OR il.location_notes LIKE '%living%'
        OR locp.location_name LIKE '%living%'
        OR ipa.indexer_header_type LIKE '%living%'
        OR ipa.indexer_header_sub_type LIKE '%living%'
        OR ipa.location_on_body LIKE '%living%'
        OR ipa.side_of_body LIKE '%living%'
        OR ipa.label LIKE '%living%'
        OR ipa.start_date LIKE '%living%'
        OR ipa.end_date LIKE '%living%'
        OR ipa.start_date_approximation LIKE '%living%'
        OR ipa.start_date_year LIKE '%living%'
        OR ipa.start_date_month LIKE '%living%'
        OR ipa.start_date_season LIKE '%living%'
        OR ipa.end_date_approximation LIKE '%living%'
        OR ipa.end_date_year LIKE '%living%'
        OR ipa.end_date_month LIKE '%living%'
        OR ipa.end_date_season LIKE '%living%'
        OR ipa.method LIKE '%living%'
        OR ipa.style LIKE '%living%'
        OR ipa.status LIKE '%living%'
        OR ipa.story LIKE '%living%'
        OR ipa.timeline_source LIKE '%living%'
        OR ipa.location_value LIKE '%living%'
        OR ipa.notes LIKE '%living%'
        OR ipa.company_value LIKE '%living%'
        OR ipa.artist_value LIKE '%living%'
        OR ipa.focus_person_value LIKE '%living%'
        OR ipa.focus_person_value LIKE '%living%'
        OR cp.company_name LIKE '%living%'
        OR ied.event_type LIKE '%living%'
        OR ied.event_sub_type LIKE '%living%'
        OR ied.event_name LIKE '%living%'
        OR ied.indexer_header_type LIKE '%living%'
        OR ied.indexer_header_sub_type LIKE '%living%'
        OR ied.start_date LIKE '%living%'
        OR ied.end_date LIKE '%living%'
        OR ied.start_date_approximation LIKE '%living%'
        OR ied.start_date_year LIKE '%living%'
        OR ied.start_date_month LIKE '%living%'
        OR ied.start_date_season LIKE '%living%'
        OR ied.end_date_approximation LIKE '%living%'
        OR ied.end_date_year LIKE '%living%'
        OR ied.end_date_month LIKE '%living%'
        OR ied.end_date_season LIKE '%living%'
        OR ied.ceremony_type LIKE '%living%'
        OR ied.union_type LIKE '%living%'
        OR ied.location_type LIKE '%living%'
        OR ied.timeline_source LIKE '%living%'
        OR ied.location_info_value LIKE '%living%'
        OR ied.notes LIKE '%living%'
        OR ied.service_type LIKE '%living%'
        OR ppe.display_name LIKE '%living%'
        OR concat_ws(' ', ppe.first_name, ppe.middle_name, ppe.last_name) LIKE '%living%'
        OR concat_ws(' ', ppe.first_name, ppe.last_name) LIKE '%living%'
        OR ppe.first_name LIKE '%living%'
        OR ppe.middle_name LIKE '%living%'
        OR ppe.last_name LIKE '%living%'
        OR ied.attendees_value LIKE '%living%'
        OR ied.union_partner_value LIKE '%living%'
        OR ied.officiant_value LIKE '%living%'
        OR locp.location_name LIKE '%living%'
        OR ied.ceremony_value LIKE '%living%'
        OR ied.reception_value LIKE '%living%'
        OR ev_search.vendor_name_value LIKE '%living%'
        OR ev_search.contact_person_value LIKE '%living%'
        OR ev_search.vendor_location_value LIKE '%living%'
        OR ev_search.service_type LIKE '%living%'
        OR eo_search.event_organizer_value LIKE '%living%'
        OR eo_search.contact_person_value LIKE '%living%'
        OR ev.vendor_location_value LIKE '%living%'
        OR ev.service_type LIKE '%living%'
    )

this query works for fewer records, but for large records it breaks the system.
I googled lots of things and come across indexing is one of the solution
So thinking to add below indexing
tbl_person_profile-
CREATE INDEX idx_person_profile_user_id ON tbl_person_profile (user_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_person_profile_catalog_id ON tbl_person_profile (catalog_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_person_profile_deleted_status ON tbl_person_profile (deleted_status);
CREATE INDEX idx_person_profile_id ON tbl_person_profile (person_profile_id);

CREATE INDEX idx_person_profile_birth_place ON tbl_person_profile (birth_place_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_person_profile_death_place ON tbl_person_profile (death_place_id);

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_person_profile_display_name ON tbl_person_profile (display_name);
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_person_profile_names ON tbl_person_profile (first_name, middle_name, last_name);
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_person_profile_secondary_name ON tbl_person_profile (secondary_name);
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_person_profile_gender ON tbl_person_profile (gender);
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_person_profile_life_status ON tbl_person_profile (life_status);

tbl_address-
CREATE INDEX idx_address_id ON tbl_address (id);
CREATE INDEX idx_address_deleted_status ON tbl_address (deleted_status);

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_address_current ON tbl_address (current_address);
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_address_vintage ON tbl_address (vintage_address);
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_address_country_state_zip ON tbl_address (country, state, zipcode);
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_address_street_neighborhood_county ON tbl_address (street_address, neighborhood, county);

tbl_address_book-
CREATE INDEX idx_address_book_person_id ON tbl_address_book (person_profile_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_address_book_is_active ON tbl_address_book (is_active);

CREATE INDEX idx_address_book_address_id ON tbl_address_book (address_id);

tbl_person_relationships-
CREATE INDEX idx_person_relationships_focus_person_id ON tbl_person_relationships (focus_person_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_person_relationships_related_person_id ON tbl_person_relationships (related_person_id);

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_person_relationships_family_nonfamily ON tbl_person_relationships (family_or_nonfamily);
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_person_relationships_connection_type ON tbl_person_relationships (connection_type);

tbl_additional_names-
CREATE INDEX idx_additional_names_person_id ON tbl_additional_names (person_profile_id);

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_additional_names ON tbl_additional_names (first_name, middle_name, last_name);
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_additional_names_type ON tbl_additional_names (type);
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_additional_names_notes ON tbl_additional_names (notes);

tbl_person_profile_storytelling-
CREATE INDEX idx_storytelling_person_id ON tbl_person_profile_storytelling (person_profile_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_storytelling_deleted_status ON tbl_person_profile_storytelling (deleted_status);

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_storytelling_caption ON tbl_person_profile_storytelling (caption);
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_storytelling_story ON tbl_person_profile_storytelling (storytelling);

tbl_indexer_vital_record-
CREATE INDEX idx_vital_record_person_id ON tbl_indexer_vital_record (person_profile_id);

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_vital_record_type ON tbl_indexer_vital_record (indexer_header_type, indexer_header_sub_type);
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_vital_record_notes ON tbl_indexer_vital_record (notes, indexer_vital_record_notes, death_notes);

tbl_indexer_location-
CREATE INDEX idx_location_person_id ON tbl_indexer_location (person_profile_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_location_deleted_status ON tbl_indexer_location (deleted_status);

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_location_value ON tbl_indexer_location (location_value);

tbl_indexer_physical_apperance-
CREATE INDEX idx_physical_apperance_person_id ON tbl_indexer_physical_apperance (person_profile_id);

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_physical_apperance_location ON tbl_indexer_physical_apperance (location_on_body);
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_physical_apperance_story ON tbl_indexer_physical_apperance (story);

tbl_indexer_event_details-
CREATE INDEX idx_event_details_person_id ON tbl_indexer_event_details (person_profile_id);

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_event_details_type ON tbl_indexer_event_details (event_type, event_sub_type);
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_event_details_notes ON tbl_indexer_event_details (notes);

tbl_event_vendor-
CREATE INDEX idx_event_vendor_id ON tbl_event_vendor (id);

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_event_vendor_name ON tbl_event_vendor (vendor_name_value, vendor_name_key);
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_event_vendor_location ON tbl_event_vendor (vendor_location_value);

tbl_event_organizer-
CREATE INDEX idx_event_organizer_id ON tbl_event_organizer (id);

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_event_organizer_name ON tbl_event_organizer (event_organizer_value, event_organizer_key);

tbl_location_profile-
CREATE INDEX idx_location_profile_id ON tbl_location_profile (location_profile_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_location_profile_deleted_status ON tbl_location_profile (deleted_status);

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_location_profile_name ON tbl_location_profile (location_name);

tbl_company_profile-
CREATE INDEX idx_company_profile_id ON tbl_company_profile (company_profile_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_company_profile_deleted_status ON tbl_company_profile (deleted_status);

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_company_profile_name ON tbl_company_profile (company_name);

tbl_person_profile_storytelling-
CREATE INDEX idx_storytelling_person_id ON tbl_person_profile (person_profile_id);
CREATE INDEX idx_storytelling_person_deleted_status ON tbl_person_profile (deleted_status);

CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx_storytelling_person_names ON tbl_person_profile (first_name, middle_name, last_name);

Kindly suggest how can I optimise and improve above query performance.
Thanks.

It'll be hard (possibly not possible) to improve the runtime because of how the query is currently written. There's multiple issues with the query itself harming the sargability such as JOIN clauses with many ORs, JOIN clauses with functions, the WHERE clause of many ORs, and the contains type of searches (with the leading and trailing wildcards). This looks like a kitchen sink search query, and should be refactored into multiple smaller queries, and the process itself should be changed. E.g. ivr.age LIKE '%living%' doesn't make sense.

@J.D. as I mention this is search query as user can search with any term, so this is why all columns are added in search as wild card search.

Even when you add a EXPLAIN for your query you wil see that th query is bad, you should only add columns that have actually values

@NageshKatke I understand, but there are better ways to architect the search workflow and code so that the query is better / more applicable for indexing and performance improvements. For example, it would be trivial in the application layer to parse the inputted search term(s) for non-numerical characters. If it contained any non-numerical characters then you can execute a measurably simpler query that doesn't include any of the numeric fields since they'd never match anyway. There are other smarter changes to result in a simpler and more efficient query.

Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78896973/indexing-and-optimize-large-query-with-multiple-joins
